# vim search and replace between number

Tags: vim

I have a pattern where there are double-quotes between numbers in a CSV file.
I can search for the pattern by [0-9]\"[0-9], but how do I retain value while removing the double quote. CSV format is like this:

```
"1234"5678","Text1","Text2"
"987654321","Text3","text4"
"7812891"3","Text5","Text6"
```

As you may notice there are double quotes between some numbers which I want to remove.

I have tried the following way, which is incorrect:

```
:%s/[0-9]\"[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/g
```

Is it possible to execute a command at every search pattern, maybe go one character forward and delete it. How can "lx" be embedded in search and replace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to capture groups.  Try:

```
:%s/\(\d\)"\(\d\)/\1\2/g
```

[A digit can also be denoted by `\d`.]

Answer (score 5):

I know that this question has been answered already, but here's another approach:

```
:%s/\d\zs"\ze\d
```

Explanation:

`%s`   Substitute for the whole buffer
`\d`   look up for a digit
`\zs` set the start of match here
`"`     look up for a double-quote
`\ze` set the end of match here
`\d`   look up for a digit

That makes the substitute command to match only the double-quote surrounded by digits.
Omitting the replacement string just deletes the match.

Answer (score 1):

You need boundaries to use in regular expression.

Try this:

```
:%s/\([0-9]\)"\([0-9]\)/\1\2/g
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit naive solution:

```
%s/^"/BEGINNING OF LINE QUOTE MARK/g
%s/\",\"/quote comma quote/g
%s/\"$/quota end of line/g
%s/\"//g
%s/quota end of line/"/g
%s/quote comma quote/","/g
%s/BEGINNING OF LINE QUOTE MARK/"/g
```

A macro can be created quite easy out of it and invoked as many times as needed.